# Dropdown auto select on data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this code to autoselect an option on a dropdown. How can I change it so as to not match the value, but tha `data-id` attribute?

```
   window.onload = function(){
       document.getElementsByName("program")[0].value=+param1;
   }
<select name="program">
    <option data-id="1234" value="567">text</option>
<option data-id="897" value="65475">text</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what has "program" to do with this? And how are you currently matching by the value? I don't see that happening.

Comment: @trincot i have updated the question. the script works as expected, but i do not want the matching to be done in the `value` but in the data-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by looking for that attribute value with [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and setting the found option's `selected` attribute.

I would also suggest to respond to the [`document.DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event instead of `window.load`:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelector('option[data-id="1234"]')
            .setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
});
```

```html
<select>
    <option data-id="12" value="7">other option</option>
    <option data-id="1234" value="567">select this</option>
</select>
```